# Insert users into levels based on sales/age

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have a List of salesmen with the fields, name, district and sales. I have sorted them by amount of articles sold but I need a way to separate them into levels and print it out. For example:

> James - 12 Sales
>
> Billy - 25 Sales
>
> 2 salesmen have reached level 1: under 50 sales

and so on. What's the easiest and best way to do this?

The loop I'm currently using for sorting looks like this:

```
    foreach (salesman n in salesmen.OrderBy(s=>s.sales))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(n.name);
        Console.WriteLine(n.sales);
    }
```

Comment: If you could post how this data is actually stored and the structure of the object you're using to do it then it would allow people to give you a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't specify code, or how you fill your objects, an approach would be:

```
Employees.ForEach(e => Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} Sale/s",e.Name, e.Sales.Count().ToString()));

    int[] levels = new int[1];
    levels[0] = 50;

    for (int i = 0; i < levels.Length; i++)
        {
        var emps = Employees.Where(e => e.Sales.Count() <= levels[i]);

        emps.ForEach(Console.WriteLine("{0} salesmen have reachead level {1}: under {2} sales", emps.Count(), i.ToString(), levels[i]);
        // Remove employees from the list that already achived the level (so they won't be counted again).
        Employess.RemoveAll(e=> e.Sales.Count() <= levels[i]);
        }
```

This is just pseudo code, it might not compile but it's the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a List of salesmen with the fields, name, district and sales. I have sorted them by amount of articles sold but I need a way to separate them into levels and print it out. For example:
>
> > James - 12 Sales
> >
> > Billy - 25 Sales
> >
> > 2 salesmen have reached level 1: under 50 sales
>
> and so on. What's the easiest and best way to do this?
>
> The loop I'm currently using for sorting looks like this:

```
foreach (salesman n in salesmen.OrderBy(s=>s.sales))
{
    Console.WriteLine(n.name);
    Console.WriteLine(n.sales);
}
```

There are no secrets in coding, and there are no shortcuts either. We first develop business logic "If a salesman makes so many sales, they are in this level, that many sales, that level" and then we turn that into computer logic. That's the art of programming, finding the best way to turn people statements into math statements. Sometimes the math statements are very verbose, sometimes they're terse. Doesn't change the end of the day, where all you can do is write the code.

The only way to get all the people in a list sorted into buckets is to go over every single part of the list. That's an iteration, or a loop. You're doing that. Then we test (`.OrderBy(s...`) for certain keywords or values.

The easiest and best way to do what you're asking is to define the business rules, then encapsulate them in logic as you're doing, with loops. You may find you end up with one list per business rule, which isn't a bad thing.

The only problem here is it sounds like you're looking for a "this is always the best way to store this data" answer, and that doesn't exist here. Until we know your entire use-case, the best we can do is to say "yes, this is appropriate". Each situation calls for a different answer. I realize this isn't much of an answer, but sometimes it's the answer you need to hear. You're doing fine, have a little confidence in yourself.